# meaning of "hysterisis"in simple words?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, experimental-physics

I have tried to learn about "hysteresis" from different engineering knowledge sources and what i am able to understand that in simple words or nutshell, it is delay between output and input

Is there anything wrong with my understanding?

Comment: It's not to do with delay - it's a difference in output depending on the direction of change of the input.

Comment: If you take a spring and gradually hang mass on it, the displacement will increase. You can plot this on a graph. Gradually remove the mass and the displacement will return 'following the same line'. Try the same test with a rubber band, and you will find that as you remove mass the displacement is higher than it was for the same mass on the way out. The fact that you are removing mass, the rubber band was previously fully stretched affects the displacement. This is hysteresis, and is due in this case to some energy being lost as the rubber band heats up

Comment: I think the most clear application of hysteresis is in various kitchen appliances involving heating - an oven, a slow-cooker, a toaster etc. "If water temperature gets below 80C, switch the heater on, and heat it to 90C." The heater has no fine-tuning, it's off or on. The bimetallic switch has two thresholds - on and off. In between them it just sustains "current state". That way you can think of hysteresis as the simplest memory circuit.

Comment: Maybe worth posting to https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/ to get an answer in true "simple words" - they're way more experienced at answering in that way than the Eng.SE community.

Comment: Actually, more worth searching: https://www.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive/search?q=hysteresis&restrict_sr=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hysterisis comes from the greek work **[υστερώ](https://www.wordreference.com/gren/%CF%85%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%81%CF%8E)**. The word means to lag behind something (usually with respect to time).  So it usually comes up **when there is time involved.**

You are right that it creeps up in many sciences. For example:

## mechanics of materials

Hysterisis in the stress strain curve. I.e. when loading a material fast enough (high strain rate) you see a curve like

[image]

The most usual reason for this behaviour is that the the material can be modelled as a spring and dashpot, so when one tries to quickly deform it, it exhibits a higher resistance (force).

## control Systems

In some cases, you can see that the response in a system lags behind the excitation (in some cases it also can seem to come before). However, in the most simple form you can have the following

[image]

Basically what you see in the picture above, is that there is an excitation to a system (see blue line) but for a considerable amount of time ($t_d$ in red) nothing seems to happen. The time $t_d$ is the hysterisis time.

Of course, hysterisis can be used to filter signals, and has other meanings.

## Other uses

If you go to the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis)  you will see that there is a (very) large number of uses of the term, all of them have a loose (at least) connection to this notion, of falling behind or following in time.

Comment: This is bit misleading I feel - it's not just time being involved, but *history*.

Comment: In some occasions, I agree history is involved. However, for the example of materials, it might just be strain rate dependance (history won't have much to do). So I opted for the more generic option time, instead of history. History implies time, while the opposite is not necessary true.

Comment: History is always involved - how did the material get to this current point in time? High strain rate means that in the past it was deformed quickly. Low strain rate means in the past it deformed slowly. The history is the thing that matters, even when it's not rate independent.

Comment: History in the broad sense, could also involve work hardening, which doesn't fall in the hysteresis category IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I like to think of hysteresis as describing deadzones in the coupling between 2 variables.

A classic example is as SF said, a heater that turns on at 80 degrees and turns off at 90 degrees. Then on again once the temp falls back down to 80. There are 10 degrees of hysteresis here.

Another example would be pulling a cart using a rope. The carts motion is coupled to your motion, but if you reverse direction, the cart will stop briefly while the rope is slacked. If the rope is 1 meter long the hysteresis will be 2 meters.

Comment: These are good examples but in many cases there is no "dead" zone, where a change in input doesn't cause any change in output (such as walking back and forth within 0.5m of your cart).

Comment: Well, as Nmech said it means different things in different contexts, just like the word "lag".

Comment: "deadzone" same as "deadband" ??

Comment: @engr I would say so. Practically speaking different companies will use slightly different terminology.